# Another gallery question

Tags: templating, ordering, responsive-images, gallery

I have looked around but cant find an answer to this.

I have a structure for my gallery page, in-which there are three separate entries called A, B and C.

There are different images within these entries. But how would I go about showing all the images within these entries in a random order?

Say I went to the gallery page and they all showed up randomly, then theres a sub navigation to the separate entries on there own?

It's probably a simple solution but templating it has me really confused. 
Thank you

Comment: Hey Spheriri, could you please consider accepting either answer that helped you, or updating the question if it wasn't solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an array and order them by random.

`{% set gallery = craft.entries.section(['galleryA','galleryB','galleryC']) %}`

Then you have to display them by random using `.order('RAND()')`

So your `for loop` looks like:

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section(gallery).order('RAND()') %}`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having separate entries, have you considered having one type of image but assigning [categories](https://craftcms.com/docs/categories) or [tags](https://craftcms.com/docs/tags) to them.

That way you could output your images in a random order using `.order('RAND()')` on the end of your `for` loop. Something like this:

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section('yourImageEntries').order('RAND()') %}`

Then if you want to output your images by specific category you can do it like this:

```
{# Fetch all of the entries related to this category #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}

{# Output them #}
{% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Example taken from the official docs [here](https://craftcms.com/support/entries-related-to-category).